# How to Hide Virtual Numerical Keyboard in IOS 16? (Appium Java)

Tags: java, ios, appium, appium-ios, ios16

I'm working on mobile automation, using Appium. I would like to hide virtual keyboard when typing a message. At the same time I want the message cursor visible. Normally when you slide down or close the keyboard, the cursor also goes away. I have been using HideKeyboard method. HideKeyboard method successfully closes normal virtual keyboard. However it does not close numerical keyboard.

Is there any way for closing the numerical keyboard while the message cursor is visible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options.
Click on "Done"/"go"/"next" or click on screen outside of the keyboard.

Also, By looking online I found this:

const doneButton = await this._driver.findElementByText('Done');
await doneButton.tap();